# Concatenating PHP Function with HTML Attribute & Cannot Use Type Object as Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, concatenation

I have 2 questions

**<< 1.>>**

I have php print code like this.

```
echo '<label class="control-label" for="'.to_string($dt->name_comp).'">'.$dt->name_comp.'</label>';
```

to_string is function that produce My Name to my_name, and it works, clear, with $dt->name_comp produce the value from database.
So.. that syntax must be html syntax like it: `<label class="control-label" for="my_name">Name Component</label>`

I wanna ask, why code above can't work? Why **my_name** not get into **for**?

I've tried this way:

```
echo '<label class="control-label" for="'. <?php to_string($dt->name_comp); ?>.'">'.$dt->name_comp.'</label>';
```

But, it same. The result is always like this: `<label class="control-label" for=" ">Name Component</label>` when I check it in firebug. So **my_name** appear outside form, doesn't enter into the **form**. Wonder why..

This is `to_string()` function:

```
function to_string($string) {
  $string = preg_replace('/[\'"]/', '', $string);
  $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '_', $string);
  $string = trim($string, '_');
  $string = strtolower($string);
  echo $string; 
}
```

**<< 2>>**

I have code for textinput like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="'.to_string($dt->name_comp).'" id="'.to_string($dt->name_comp).'" placeholder="'.$dt->name_comp.'"  value="'.$dt['/name_comp/'].'">';
```

But, there is an error: **Fatal error cannot use object of type workspace_mockup_2\Models\Component as array** What should I enter there?
Need some advice.. Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of `to_string()` should be:

```
return $string;
```

When you do:

```
echo "something".to_string(something_else);
```

The sequence of events is this:

1. `to_string(something_else)` is called.
2. `to_string` echoes the string it creates.
3. `to_string` returns `undefined`.
4. `"something"` is concatenated with `undefined`, which results in `"something"`.
5. `"something"` is echoed.

This is why `to_string`'s result is echoes outside the label, because it is echoed in step 2, while the label is echoed in step 5.